# Rename the wsus database susdb before install (SQL Database)

Tags: sql, wsus

is it possible to rename the wsus database, on a SQL Server, before install the role?

In our company we have two wsus server, one for the client laptops and pc's and the other for our datacenter server. The problem is that i cannot have two databases named 'SUSDB'. Is there a way that i can rename the Database *before* deploying the Database onto the SQL Server. I know that i can rename the database in the registry after the installation but this is a dirty way and can cause problems.

Thanks and kind regards

Thommy

Comment: Is there a reason you don't have one WSUS and two WSUS groups?

Comment: We simply dont want to have it at one server because the administration is separated as well. So should the two servers be separated.

Thanks for your reply

Answer (score 1):

1.Install the first WSUS sever and use MSSSQL with default SUSDB name.

2.Install the second WSUS server and use the WID database as a store.

3.Setup second as you wish (Central Management-replica, Distributed or Independent like you wish)

Answer (score 1):

I don't know of any way to change the default name during install.  You're probably stuck with renaming the database later.

I'd install the second server onto WID and move the new database onto SQL with a new name to avoid any downtime for the existing WSUS server.

(You'd need to edit the registry on the new server to change `HKLM\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\UpdateServices\Server\Setup\SqlServerName` to be your SQL Server and `HKLM\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\UpdateServices\Server\Setup\SqlDatabaseName` to be the second database, but it sounds like you know that.)

Answer (score 0):

I know this is an old post, but another option that increases the administration separation of the two servers is ask for a new instance on the SQL server and point the new WSUS install to the new instance.  No moving of DBs or messing with the registry, keeps it clean all the way around.

Answer (score -1):

Yes you can I already did it but after installation, you can change the installed server DB then install the new server and rename it's DB also, in all scenario you will make a down time for 15 or 20 min for the running WSUS server which is not a critical service in any network
you can use these links to do that

https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/administration/windows-server-update-services/manage/wid-to-sql-migration

https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/4419/renaming-physical-database-file-names-for-a-sql-server-database/

Comment: thats a link only answer?!

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/517891)